# estimation on the Poisson equation

Tags: sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a bounded region with the smooth boundary.
Consider the Poisson equation with the Dirichlet boundary condition:

$$\begin{align*}
  - \nabla^2 \phi &= f \\
  \phi \vert_{\partial \Omega} &= 0
\end{align*} $$

This has a unique weak solution in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$.

Then $$\| \nabla \phi \|_{2} \le C \| f \|_{H^2}$$
for some constant $C$, independent of $\nabla \phi$ and $f$.
(Here $\| \|_{2}$ denotes the $L^2$ norm and $\| f \|_{H^2} := \| f \|_{2} + \| \nabla f \|_{2} + \| \nabla^2 f \|_{2} $.)

I think

[Estimation of gradients in Poisson's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767224/estimation-of-gradients-in-poissons-equation)

is enough for explaining this.

However, I have no idea about analogous estimation for Neumann condition:
$$\begin{align*}
  - \nabla^2 \phi &= f \quad \textrm{on} \  \Omega \\
  \nabla \phi \cdot n &= 0 \quad \textrm{on} \  \partial \Omega
\end{align*} $$
has a unique weak solution on $H^{1}(\Omega)$, provided that $\int_{\Omega} f =0$.

In this case, $\| \nabla \phi\|_{2} \le C \| f\|_{H^2}$.

---

The paper says that this is the 'trace estimate' but I have no idea about it... Any hint will be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You always have $\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2} \leq \|\phi\|_{H^1} \leq \|\phi\|_{H^2}$ for all $\phi \in H^2$, it does not have to be a solution of a PDE.

Comment: Oh I made a terrible typo in my question... thanks for your comment

Comment: The right side is about $f$, not $\phi$.